# Docusign Template List Folder by name not working

Tags: docusignapi

All,

I have read and coded the following listed in documentation
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list/

In above the following is shown

folder  string
The query value can be a folder name or folder ID. The response will only return templates in the specified folder.

when I use folder id it's found but nothing is returned when I use folder name. I have verified that folder name matches
Also tried to use a "[{"name": "GTP"}]" but that will result in a error
HELP!

C#

`templatesApi.ListTemplates(AccountId, new TemplatesApi.ListTemplatesOptions { sharedByMe = "true", folder = "GTP" }); // no results`


`templatesApi.ListTemplates(AccountId, new TemplatesApi.ListTemplatesOptions { sharedByMe = "true", folder = "bba1e719-1f38-4a1a-a8cc-03c4960de336" }); // works`

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine for me when I am using below API call and testing using Postman,

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/templates?folder=FolderName
```

Answer (score 0):

As Amit says, the API call can use the name of a folder, but **only if the folder is not a shared folder**. To list the contents of a shared folder you need to use the folderId.

I have filed DocuSign internal bug report EC-1163. Please ask DocuSign customer service or your DocuSign technical contact to add your organization's information to the bug report. That will help increase its priority.

**Workaround:** Use the Shared Folder's id for the search.